# OpenFileMapping: GetLastError=2

Tags: c++, winapi, shared-memory, citrix

I'm trying to share memory between two processes C# (EXE) and C++ (DLL). 
The C++ DLL is dynamically loaded by a Citrix receiver process.

Below is my C# and C++ code:

```
private void Test()
{
    string data = "Hello";
    _memoryMap = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("14614C87-8D7F-45FC-8D59-DCBF1715A715", data.Length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);

    var stream = _memoryMap.CreateViewStream();

    using (BinaryWriter binReader = new BinaryWriter(stream))
    {
        binReader.Write(data);
    }
}
```

```
void readFromMemoryMap()
{   
    HANDLE hMapObject = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, L"14614C87-8D7F-45FC-8D59-DCBF1715A715");

    char buffer[2000];
    if (hMapObject == NULL)
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "OpenFileMapping: GetLastError=%d", GetLastError());        
    }

    char *fileBuffer = (char *)MapViewOfFile(hMapObject, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 6);

    UnmapViewOfFile(fileBuffer);
    CloseHandle(hMapObject);
}
```

I took care of writing and reading an object sequence. My C# application's memory map handle didn't crash. I have run this code using an administrator account which has rights.

I am facing the below error. Can anyone help me with the case of this error?

I followed below link for fix this issue.

[OpenFileMapping ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?451664-OpenFileMapping-ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)

Comment: The path names are both relative paths are you running both programs with the same working directory?

Comment: Documentation suggests you prefix the filename with "Global\\" or "Local\\" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Memory/creating-named-shared-memory

Comment: @ric: There are no file names involved. Those are object names.

Comment: @ric not both are in different directory.

Comment: @Neil _memoryMap = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("Global\\O14614C87-8D7F-45FC-8D59-DCBF1715A715", data.Length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite) - It hang on

Comment: @Neil _memoryMap = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("Local\\O14614C87-8D7F-45FC-8D59-DCBF1715A715", data.Length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite) - It gives same error

Comment: @mahen - in what problem look (with winobj) are section is created, are it not closed.

Comment: @RbMm- winobj close in C++ dll  and not from C# exe

Comment: @mahen - winobj this is tool which let you look nt object namespace. this not related to c#/c++

Comment: CreateOrOpen() is too wishy-washy.  This can only work correctly if the C# program starts first and created the mmf.  If the C++ program starts first then you'll get this error.  So start fixing this by using CreateNew or CreateFromFile and strongly consider using the Process class to start the C++ program after that.

Comment: @ Hans Used CreateNew  API and gives the same error

Comment: So which one runs first, C# or C++ code? Does C# process still run when C++ code is called? Maybe C# process still runs, but closes `_memoryMap` too early. Really, need [mcve], otherwise this is all just wild guesswork.

Comment: You are just trying stuff at random. You are reading comments, looking for function names, changing your code trying everything out without really understanding it. Of course this approach doesn't yield success. Start with two C++ programs and see if you can make them play nice together. Once you can achieve that, go on from there.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I already created small example C#(exe) write and C++(exe) read. It is working fine. But the same code is not working in c++ (DLL) which load via CITRIX receiver.

Comment: @zett42 I uploaded the small POC code in this link. Please guide me https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/398319-send-message-to-citrix-client-driver-from-c-application/#comment-2022120

Comment: Finally i found the cause it is due to unicode text in C++. Remove "L" and it start to work. Thanks you all guys to help me out to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Try prefixing the object name with Global\ like it says here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory